# Encoding to UTF-8 files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, encoding, utf-8, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm writing a MapReduce program in order to clean some files stored in HDFS, for that i have to encode all files in UTF-8, i tried to encode the Text value in my mapper but i still have errors in my result file.

```
if(encoding.compareTo("UTF-8")!=0){
            final Charset fromCharset = Charset.forName(encoding);
            final Charset toCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            String fixed = new String(value.toString().getBytes(fromCharset), toCharset); 
            result= new String(fixed);
```

I also custom the LineReader in order to encode the bytes readed into UTF-8 before that it's stored in Text Object.

```
 //buffer contain the data readed in a line of the file
 String s = new String(buffer, startPosn, appendLength);
            byte ptext[] = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(s).array();              
            str.append(ptext, 0, ptext.length);
```

Can you help me please !

Comment: What actual `Writable` types are you using in your program? Your above code snippets don't really tell the story of how the `byte[]` are read from and written to actual `Writable` implementations (and these two are probably where your issue lies).

Comment: Thank you for your response @ArminBraun , i use only Text i create a `Writable` Object and i use it as output in the mapper but nothing happend because the Text in input of the mapper is incorrectly built: 
`25196921|03|Pr�l�vement obligatoire|||2015-12-16 00:00:00.0`
I think that the question is how can i change the input parameters type of the mapper in order to change Text in other object.(Because Text object can manipulateonly UFT-8 characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the response:

```
if(encoding.compareTo("CP1252")==0)
        valueInString= new String(value.getBytes(),
            0, value.getLength(), 
            StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    else valueInString=value.toString();
```